# limit user only to specific data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three types of users "Admin," "Manager," and "Employee." Also, I have an accounts model. All of them can show these accounts. I want to limit employees' access to these accounts. I put the Ids of these accounts in an array and did a limit like the code below. My question is, I had 15 endpoints related to the accounts, Is the best way to do it like this, or may there be a solution that does it without editing all these endpoints?

```
def index
  if @current_user.user_type == 'Admin'
    @accounts = Accounts.all
    @accounts = optional_paginate(@accounts)
  elsif @current_user.user_type == 'Employee'
    @accounts = Account.where(id: ACCOUNTS_IDS)
    @accounts = optional_paginate(@business_accounts)
  else
    @business_accounts = optional_paginate(Account.all.includes(:account_managers).exclude_pending)
  end
end
```

The **ACCOUNTS_IDS** is an array of accounts ids that the employees can access to them only.

Comment: You can take a look at the [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) gem, then you can define a scope which defines which type of user can load which accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy works, but I think you're sensing that it's not ideal.

- You had to hard-code an array of Account IDs from your database, which is never a good idea. If you ever needed to migrate or seed or recreate the database, those IDs could change.
- You have this code repeated 15 times(so it's not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))
- If an account with an id in ACCOUNTS_IDS is ever deleted, imagine what will happen to each of these controller actions.
- Adding to or removing from the accounts (ACCOUNTS_IDS) that Employees can see requires you to change your codebase and push those changes.

I'd suggest doing a few things differently:

#### 1. Use an authorization gem

I personally love [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit), but there are [other popular options](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization)

#### 2. Don't hard-code database information

As mentioned before, the IDs can change and code that relies on a specific record having a specific ID (or relying on that specific record to exist) is brittle.

It's much better to add a column to your table to control this.

Here's an example migration:

```rb
add_column :accounts, :restricted, :boolean, default: true, null: false

ACCOUNTS_IDS = [1, 2, 3, 4] #just an e.g.

Account.where(id: ACCOUNTS_IDS).update_column(restricted: false)
```

`:restricted` could also be something easier to understand, e.g. `:visible_to_employees`

Now you can make scopes in your Account model:

```rb
# /models/account.rb

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  scope :restricted, -> { where(restricted: true) }
  scope :unrestricted, -> { where(restricted: false) }
  ...
end
```

This allows you to do `Account.all` to get everything, `Account.restricted` to get some, and `Account.unrestricted` to get the others.

This **also** allows you to add a view form where accounts could be made visible to Employees without having to change the code of your application.

#### 3. Do this in the model, not in the controller

Lean towards having more code in your models and less code in your controllers.

(this will also help you when you implement a Pundit scope)

```rb
# models/user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def authorized_accounts
    case user_type
    when 'Admin'
      Account.all
    when 'Employee'
      Account.unrestricted
    else
      Account.all.includes(:account_managers).exclude_pending
    end
end
```

Now your controller can be greatly simplified:

```rb
def index
  @accounts = optional_paginate(@current_user.authorized_accounts)
end
```